# c++ error checking fstream open() command and general stringstream error handling

Tags: c++, fstream

I have a function that creates an opens a file using `ftstream`. What is the best way to add error checking to this, so if the file opening fails then exit the program?

Also how can you test if writing to a stream fails i.e. if `outputfile << ss.str();` fails ?

```
OpenFile() {

 std::ofstream outputfile;
 outputfile.open("test.txt);

 ss << "Testing" << "\n";
 outputfile << ss.str();
}
```

Comment: What kind of error you want check for? What shall be the consequence?

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but get in the habit of initializing with appropriate values instead of using a default constructor followed by setting the state you're after. That is, change `std::ofstream outputfile; outputfile.open("test.txt");` to `std::ofstream outputfile("test.txt');`.

Answer (score 1):

All streams convert to a Boolean value indicating whether they are OK to use (i.e., the stream converts to `true`) or not:

```
std::ofstream outputFile(fileName);
if (!outputFile) {
    std::cout << "failed to open file '" << fileName << "' for writing\n";
}
```

Sadly, the state doesn't contain a huge amount information on what went wrong. Essentially, there are only 4 different stated:

1. `good()`: none of the other error flags is set
2. `eof()`: the stream has "touched" the end of the stream (applicable primarily for input streams)
3. `bad()`: the stream is in a fundamentally broken state
4. `fail()`: an operation on the stream failed, e.g., it couldn't read some input (or the stream turned `bad()`)

That is, there isn't a way to tell *why* a stream isn't good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `outputfile.is_open()` to tell if the file was opened successfully. To later see if error has occurred on the stream you can call `outputfile.fail()`. To go the C++ way, operator `!` of your `ofstream` returns the value of `fail()`. So your conditional statement could look like this:

```
if (!outputfile) // Will enter if there was an error.
```